# Magento 2 : How disable a footer links in luma theme

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, footer, footer-links

I try to disable that's footer links:

[image]

have defaulted in luma theme but I not found the configuration to disable that.

How to disable that's link without touch the core files.

Answer (score 1):

> Footer Links Remove

**List of below link block:**

```
Privacy and Cookie Policy: privacy-policy-link

Search Terms: search-term-popular-link

Contact Us: contact-us-link

Advanced Search: catalog-search-advanced-link

Orders and Returns: sales-guest-form-link
```

**To add new links to footer links, use this code:**

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="your-link-name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Title</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path-of-your-page</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove footer links, create `default.xml` file on path `app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout` and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
           <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

This will remove footer links.
To disable links use below code in `default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
           <referenceBlock name="footer_links" display="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Using this, PHP objects will be still generated and available for manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml file in your app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/layout folder and add the following line to the  container

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
```

This will remove the footer links you are trying to remove.